# how to use wordpress 3.0 multi sites functionality?

Tags: wordpress

how to enalble wordpress 3.0 multisites and open registration to public people?

Comment: Despite being a poorly worded question, you should head on over to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To enable this feature, simply open
>   your wp-config.php file located in
>   your WordPress root folder. Then add
>   the following line anywhere in the
>   file:
>
> ```
> define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
> ```
>
> Once you have done that, you should be
>   able to access the network page from
>   Tools » Network

Source: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-enable-multi-site-option-in-wordpress-3-0/